# Android set margins for control inside webview doesn't work

Tags: android, layout, webview

I have a webview, a functionality that add a new button to this webview, the problem here is I can't not set the margins to this button and it always show on the top, left of webview.

Or any solutions for my situation: I want to add a control at specify position(x, y) inside a webview, when users scroll on the webview, the control will be scroll as well and always be shown at exactly position I have set before?

My xml layout:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:id="@+id/mainLayout"
   >

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/myWebView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"

        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        android:visibility="visible">
    </WebView>
</LinearLayout>
```

My code to create new button is:

```
private void createButton(WebView wv){
        //LinearLayout relativeLayout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.mainLayout);
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(60,60, Gravity.TOP);
        params.setMargins(50, 50, 0, 0);// Doesn't work at all here

        android.widget.Button button = new android.widget.Button(this);
        button.setText("Hello button");

        button.setLayoutParams(params);

        wv.addView(button);
    }
```

Any helps will be thanked in advanced

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use `WebView.LayoutParams` instead of `LinearLayout.LayoutParams`.

Replace

```
LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(60,60, Gravity.TOP);
params.setMargins(50, 50, 0, 0);
```

with

```
WebView.LayoutParams params = new WebView.LayoutParams(60, 60, 50, 50);
```